# How to set rigidbody2d on object asleep after resetting its position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I set the sleeping mode of an object to "start asleep" so that when starting the scene, the rigidbody waits for an interaction(a mouse click) to activate. i want to have the object reset its position just in case the object gets out of bounds on the main screen for some reason. problem is that the object is not "asleep" when resetting its position. btw, i use triggers (an edge collider to be exact) to detect the object off-screen.

Here is the code for the object.

```
void Awake()
{
    initialPosition = transform.position;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
}


void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Boundary")
    {

    transform.position = initialPosition;
    rb.Sleep();
    

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure that the rigidbody `Sleep` function is what you want in this case, since it is only intended to briefly pause the physics. You should look into [Rigidbody.isKinematic}(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) instead. It will keep your object interactive, but will halt physics affections, effectively freezing it in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a RigidBody's Constraints to freeze it's position:

```
_rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;
```

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html

You may also be able to use `IsKinematic = false` to "pause" the RigidBody as well.

```
_rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
```